How can I create a shared framework with resources?
I am optimizing my app size and encountered a problem with spm: how can I create a shared(between main app executable and app's extensions) frameworks with its own resources? I created a simple project to reproduce my problem: empty SwiftUI project with a widget extension and a package 'Resources', here is the description of the package:
let package = Package(
    name: "Resources",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Resources",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["Resources"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Resources",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "Sources",
            resources: [
                .process("Resources")
            ]
        )
    ]
)

both main and the widget targets include the library "Resources" in their "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded content", main target embeds it and the widget target doesn't(Do not embed option).
here it the screenshot of this section for the main target
and for the widget target
I expect that Xcode will create a separate resources framework with a Resources.bundle included in it. Instead of it I see duplicated Resources.bundle in both targets. What do I understand wrong?
this is emerge's tools analysis of my project
